# Spring ApplicationContext Running twice

Tags: java, spring-mvc, applicationcontext

I want to migrate Spring WebMvcConfigurerAdapter Configuration with Spring security.
Now i get the problem that i get 2 ApplicationContextes and my Singelten Classes are Statefull.
Here my web.xml and my FrontendConfig.

Please be indulgent with me. Im a newbie :)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">


  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
      de.wiegand.mytransport.frontend.config.FrontendConfig
    </param-value>
  </context-param>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
      org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>
                org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                de.wiegand.mytransport.frontend.config.FrontendConfig
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Configuration class

```
@Import({ StackEnvironment.class }) 
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({ "de.wiegand" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@Configuration
@ImportResource({ "/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml", "/WEB-INF/springsecurity.taglib.xml" })
public class FrontendConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        // 2DO: Wrong ??????
        registry.addResourceHandler("/assets/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/")
                .setCachePeriod(31556926);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/css/")
                .setCachePeriod(31556926);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**").addResourceLocations("/img/")
                .setCachePeriod(31556926);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/js/")
                .setCachePeriod(31556926);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/pages/");  //
        resolver.setSuffix(".xhtml");

        return resolver;
    }
}
```

THX

Answer (score 0):

You've declared the same `@Configuration` class

```
 de.wiegand.mytransport.frontend.config.FrontendConfig
```

in both the `ContextLoaderListener` and the `DispatcherServlet`.

Both of these create an `ApplicationContext`. Since the `DispatcherServlet` context (child) has access to the beans in the `ContextLoaderListener` context (parent), you'll end up with duplicate beans or even initialization errors (depending on the config).

Your `FrontendConfig` is a `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` and should therefore be the context that the `DisaptcherServlet` loads.

If you have no other context (application-wide contxt), remove your `ContextLoaderListener` declaration in the `web.xml`.

Comment: Thanks for response.
I just have the web.xml and the security.xml.
My attempt to get it without the ContextLoaderListener is faild cause the Spring Security need that in my oppinion?

Whole project as zip.   http://uploaded.net/file/yjau2hzl
THANK U

Comment: @Moinsn I don't know what Spring Security needs. What you can do is split into two `@Configuration` classes: one for spring security with the `ContextLoaderListener` and one for the `DispatcherServlet`.

Comment: That sounds like a solution.
Can u tell me what i have to do to split the Config and configure the ContextLoaderListener and the Dispatcher in Java?

Comment: @Moinsn Create a new `@Configuration` class that contains the security configuration. USe that class for the `contextConfigLocation` of `ContextLoaderListener` declaration in the `web.xml`.

Comment: The configuration class for the security and the contextConfigLocation  have to extend the WebMvcConfigurerAdapter to? Sry I'm a little overwhelmed at the moment.

Comment: @Moinsn Please read the [javadoc for `WebMvcConfigurer`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.html), which is the interface of `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`. Maybe also read an example like this one: http://www.luckyryan.com/2013/02/07/migrate-spring-mvc-servlet-xml-to-java-config/